# How to prevent Laravel from loading full set of data on object property access after already querying a restricted set

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

Hi fellow Laravel hackers,

I've got a problem with constrained Eloquent queries. I try to limit the queried data to a minimum and therefore using eager load constraints. The problem, however, is that after I queried the data, every access to a property of my model (opening_times) results in a return of all the associated options and losing the contraint. The property is backed by a hasMany relationship in my model. Take a look at the following code:

```
$store = BRModels\Store::with(
[   'coordinates',
    'openingTimes',
    'user'
])
->with(
[
    'openingTimeExceptions' => function($query) { $query->where('day', '=', date('Y-m-d'));},
    'openingTimes' => function($query) { $query->where('day', '=', date('N')); }
])
->find($id);

die(json_encode($store));
```

gives an output containing the following:

```
{
    ...,
    "opening_times": [
        {
            "id": "3",
            "store_id": "1",
            "day": "3",
            "open": "05:00:00",
            "close": "13:00:00",
            "open_additional": "16:30:00",
            "close_additional": "23:30:00"
        }
    ],
    ...
}
```

doing exactly what I want. However, when I change the last line to the following:

```
die(json_encode($store->opening_times));
```

my wonderful restriction is gone, as you can see in

```
[
    {
        "id": "1",
        "store_id": "1",
        "day": "1",
        "open": "05:00:00",
        "close": "13:30:00",
        "open_additional": "16:30:00",
        "close_additional": "21:00:00"
    },
    ...,
    {
        "id": "7",
        "store_id": "1",
        "day": "7",
        "open": "07:00:00",
        "close": "23:00:00",
        "open_additional": null,
        "close_additional": null
    }
]
```

As you (hopefully) can see, I get all entries related to the original item and not only the ones I got when doing the restricted query. If you cannot see it, blame me for explaining badly and give me a shout.

My question: How can I avoid that accessing an already queried object property returning a newly queried set of data without the former restriction?

I would be glad if anyone could help me!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jut stick to one convention:

```
with('openingTimes')
// then
die(json_encode($store->openingTimes));
```

and you'll be good.

Mind that relations are saved as array keys:

```
$store->openingTimes; // setRelation('openingTimes', $value)
$store->opening_times; // setRelation('opening_times', $value)
```

then:

```
$store->getRelations();
// array(
//  'openingTimes' => ... ,
//  'opening_times' => ...
// );
```

This happens because Eloquent calls relations as `dynamic properties` and both `camelCased` and `snake_cased` calls will be forwarded to `camelCased()` method.

That said, if you defined your relation as `opening_times()` it would never work.

Comment: Sometimes one just needs a push into the right direction. Thank you very much! It works exactly as I want it to.